# NumPy: Sort and sum data into target indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Another data summation problem. I have a (large) data array and and array with indices of the same length.

```
data = [1.0, 10.0, 100.0]
indices = [0, 2, 0]
```

The goal is to sum the entries of `data` into a new array such that the entry at index `k` contributes to `out[k]`. For the above example, the result would be

```
out = [101.0, 0.0, 10.0]
```

The length of `out` can be specified beforehand, or just taken to be `max(indices)`.

(The problem is similar to [NumPy: Sort and sum data into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107571/numpy-sort-and-sum-data-into-array/38107667#38107667) with the exception that here, the *target* indices are given.)

Doing it in a loop works,

```
import numpy as np

out = np.zeros(2)
for val, k in zip(data, indices):
    out[k] += val
```

but is slow if `data` is large.

Any hints on how to speed this up? (Array comprehensions?)

Comment: As listed in the answers to the linked dup target, both `np.add.at` and `np.bincount` work. But for performance I would go with `bincount`.

Comment: What version of Python are you running? If you're on 2.x You should use `izip` instead of `zip` which is the generator version of `zip` from 3.x backported to 2.x -- MUCH more memory efficient